# Can I slice on an unordered time series index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was watching a video by Wes McKinney on pandas time series.  He mentioned that Pandas throws an exception if you try to slice a time series index where the index is unordered.

However, when I tried this myself, it appeared to work. Although, I don't understand why.

Here's an example:

I used some of the code examples from the Wes McKinney talk on pandas time series (it's on YouTube). However, the expected output didn't match the actual output.  The video is somewhat old, from 2012, so perhaps he's made this change in later versions of Pandas, but I'm wondering if that's it or if I'm either misunderstanding him or I'm doing something wrong.

I'm running Pandas version 0.22.0 on an Ubuntu 18.04 based system.

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ts  = pd.Series(np.arange(1000), index = date_range)
ts2 = ts.take(np.random.permutation(len(ts)))
ts2['2015-01-01':'2016-01-01']
```

I expected to get a `TimeSeriesError: Partial indexing only valid for ordered series.`

I actually got data that looks like this:

```
2015-08-27    238
2015-04-11    100
2015-08-17    228
2015-12-10    343
2015-08-06    217
2015-02-16     46
2015-01-29     28
...
2015-06-08    158
2015-04-16    105
2015-03-08     66
2015-11-22    325
2015-10-21    293
2015-10-04    276
2015-08-02    213
2015-09-19    261
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) mentions: "**Note:** While pandas does not force you to have a sorted date index, some of these methods may have unexpected or incorrect behavior if the dates are unsorted."

Answer (score 0):

It works with string indexing, but not with a datetime object outside of the expected zone. (Although it's not always predictable.)

```
import datetime as dt
ts2['2015-01-01':'2021-01-01']  # works
ts2[dt.date(2015, 1, 1):dt.date(2016, 1, 1)]  # works
ts2[dt.date(2015, 1, 1):dt.date(2021, 1, 1)]  # ValueError
```

There's [an issue on Github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17856), but Jeff Reback said it's not a bug; the docs do warn of "[unexpected behaviour](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#indexing)"

Comment: I think this is a different issue, looks like this is using an exact match so you will need to provide 2 dates that actually exist in the index (with a 1000 dates around 2015 - 2021 would  not be in the range). Giving it 2 dates in the range makes this work even with an unsorted `DateTimeIndex` - perhaps with unintended behaviour.

Comment: So is there no exact rule? Qualified my answer a bit